# Blazor server-side with multiple database based on hostname

Tags: blazor, multi-tenant, blazor-server-side

I'm starting to lose my mind on this:

I'm trying to build a Blazor application where the end-user will be connected to one database or another depending on the hostname they're acceding the application from. 
For example, subdomain1.application.com will connect to one database and subdomain2.application.com will connect to another database. I believe this principle is called Mutlitenancy(?).

To achieve this, I build a 'master' database that stores the hostnames and the connection strings to the different databases. Then I have a `TenantService` class that loads the different connections and return the connection string corresponding to the current base URI using `IHttpContextAccessor` by injection. Everything works fine in debug.

The problem I'm facing occured when I tried to host my application on Azure. `IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext` is null, therefore I cannot access the base URI. I've read on multiple threads that `HttpContext` does not exist with SignalR nor should be used with Blazor server-side.

Things I've tried :

- Inject `NavigationManager` into my `TenantService` but got an exception `InvalidOperationException: 'RemoteNavigationManager' has not been initialized`

I've seen people talk about SignalR hubs to access the Context, but I cannot get my head around on how this works.
If anyone has built something similar, I'm all ears to a better approach. Maybe I need to start over and not use url-based multitenancy at all. Thanks for anyone's help.

**EDIT:** Here's more details on how I implemented it today.

#### TenantHolder.cs

```cs
public class TenantHolder : ITenantHolder
{
    private List<Tenants> _tenants;

    public TenantHolder(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        using (var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var provider = scope.ServiceProvider;
            using (var context = provider.GetRequiredService<MasterContext>())
                _tenants = context.Tenants.ToList();    // Retrieve all the existing tenants from the MasterContext
                                                        // which is permanantly connected to a master database
        }
    }

    public string GetCurrentTenant(HttpContext context)
    {
        var hostname = context.Request.Host.Value;
        var tenant = _tenants.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Url == hostname);
        return tenant.ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

#### TenantService.cs

```cs
public class TenantService : ITenantService
{
    private readonly HttpContext _httpContext;
    private readonly ITenantHolder _tenantHolder;

    public TenantService(IHttpContextAccessor accessor, ITenantHolder tenantHolder)
    {
        _httpContext = accessor.HttpContext;    // Works fine in local but NULL when hosted on Azure
        _tenantHolder = tenantHolder;
    }

    public string GetCurrentTenant()
        => _tenantHolder.GetCurrentTenant(_httpContext);
}
```

#### TenantContext.cs

```cs
public class TenantContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> // Shorten
{
    private readonly ITenantService _tenantService;
    
    public TenantContext(DbContextOptions<TenantContext> options, ITenantService tenantService)
        : base(options)
    {
        _tenantService = tenantService;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) 
    {
        string connectionString = _tenantService.GetCurrentTenant();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString)) ;   // TODO: throw an exception or something

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    }
}
```

#### Startup.cs

```cs
services.AddDbContext<TenantContext>(opts => opts.UseSqlServer(masterConnectionString));  // Connected to the master database before the tenant management changes it
services.AddDbContext<MasterContext>(opts => opts.UseSqlServer(masterConnectionString));

services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddSingleton<ITenantHolder, TenantHolder>();
services.AddScoped<ITenantService, TenantService>();
```

Comment: You can only inject `NavigationManager` into Razor Components. Can't you forward that when you call the `TenantService`?

Comment: Not sure if this helps as I'm a bit hazy on your details but, there's a concept of a `DbContextFactory` in Net5 that gives you a lot of flexibility on your database connection.  It all depends on what you're doing with your DbContext.  Are the databases different structures, and thus have different models, or exactly the same structure and thus share the same model.  Change the context and the same model fits all.  If so then you just need to get the right connection string based on the site.  The connnection strings can live in appsettings.  Give me a few points if you want more help .

Comment: Here's a snippet if it helps:            
var dbContext = configuration.GetValue<string>("Configuration:DBContext");    
            services.AddDbContextFactory<WeatherForecastDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(dbContext), ServiceLifetime.Singleton);

Comment: @ShaunCurtis Sorry if I didn't provide enough details. Basically I need to read the base uri from which the end user comes to the website and connect to a database accordingly. I added some details to the post to clear things up.

Comment: @JHBonarius What do you mean by 'forward'?

Comment: Well, I guess you call `GetCurrentTenant` for you Razor Component? I would then change the parameter from a `HttpContext` to a `NavigationManager`. (With "forward" I mean "pass as argument when calling")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User @enet deleted their answer but it helped me find the solution. Thank you @JHBonarius too.
Here's the new implementation for anyone facing the same issue.

#### App.razor.cs

CodeBehind file for `App.razor`, this can be done directly in `App.razor`

```cs
public partial class App : ComponentBase
{
    [Inject] private NavigationManager _navigationManager { get; set; }
    [Inject] private IContextFactory _contextFactory { get; set; }

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var uri = new Uri(_navigationManager.Uri);
        _contextFactory.Hostname = uri.Host; // Or uri.Authority if you need the port

        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

#### ContextFactory.cs

```cs
public class ContextFactory : IContextFactory
{
    public string Hostname { get; set; }
}
```

#### TenantHolder.cs

```cs
public class TenantHolder : ITenantHolder
{
    private List<Tenants> _tenants;

    public TenantHolder(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        using (var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var provider = scope.ServiceProvider;
            using (var context = provider.GetRequiredService<MasterContext>())
                _tenants = context.Tenants.ToList();    // Retrieve all the existing tenants from the MasterContext
                                                        // which is permanantly connected to a master database
        }
    }

    public string GetCurrentTenant(HttpContext context, string hostname)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hostname) && context != null)
            hostname = context.Request.Host.Value;

        var tenant = _tenants.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Url == hostname);
        return tenant.ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

#### TenantService.cs

```cs
public class TenantService : ITenantService
{
    private readonly HttpContext _httpContext;
    private readonly ITenantHolder _tenantHolder;
    private readonly IContextFactory _contextFactory;

    public TenantService(IHttpContextAccessor accessor, ITenantHolder tenantHolder, IContextFactory contextFactory)
    {
        _httpContext = accessor.HttpContext; // HttpContext is still required when DbContext is accessed from a controller
        _contextFactory = contextFactory;
        _tenantHolder = tenantHolder;
    }

    public string GetCurrentTenant()
        => _tenantHolder.GetCurrentTenant(_httpContext, _contextFactory.Hostname);
}
```

#### TenantContext.cs -unchanged

#### Startup.cs

```cs
services.AddDbContext<TenantContext>(opts => opts.UseSqlServer(masterConnectionString));  // Connected to the master database before the tenant management changes it
services.AddDbContext<MasterContext>(opts => opts.UseSqlServer(masterConnectionString));

services.AddScoped<IContextFactory, ContextFactory>();

services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddSingleton<ITenantHolder, TenantHolder>();
services.AddScoped<ITenantService, TenantService>();
```

*Import note:* This only works because `App.OnInitializedAsync()` is called before `TenantContext` is initialized. I'm not sure this will work 100% of the time, I would love to have a confirmation that this is safe, but that'll do for now. Thanks for anyone involved!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion was going to be to put your Tenant DbContext in TenantService and provide a Loader Method to initialize it.  This could be called by a component you place in App.  Basically the same as using `App.OnInitializedAsync`.  In my solution you then access the DbContext through TenantService.

Pseudo Code looks something like this:

```
        public TenantDbContext MyDbContext { get; private set; }

        // Checker to make sure it's loaded
        public bool IsLoaded => MyDbContext != null;

        // called from the TenantDbLoader UI component Not another service)
        public void LoadCurrentTenant(string siteUrl)
        {
            // figure out the DbContext
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TenantDbContext>();
            options.UseSqlServer("correctconnectionstring");
            MyDbContext = new TenantDbContext(options.Options);
        }
```

Component

```
    public class TenantDbLoader : ComponentBase
    {
        [Inject] private NavigationManager NavManager { get; set; }

        [Inject] private TenantService TenService { get; set; }

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            TenService.LoadCurrentTenant(NavManager.Uri);
        }

    }
```

I haven't tested it, so no guarantees!

On timing for your solution, I think the context isn't built till it's used, so as long as the horse is in front of the cart you're OK.

Good coding.

Comment: I suppose it would work the same as my solution. The only downside I see with this one is that it's only accessible from a Blazor component. I'm also working with controllers where the TenantContext is needed, but it's a good alternative!