# Blazor .net 8 multitenancy - How to get the Hostname in class ApplicationDbContext.OnConfiguring (not in component) Converting from ASP.NET Core 3

Tags: blazor, .net-8.0

In my Blazor .net 8 project, I am trying to get the  Hostname within my ApplicationDbContext.OnConfiguring class. I am trying to reuse some of my asp.net core 3 code to work with multiple databases, but I cannot to find the solution to getting hostname.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>(options)
{
    private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider;//Should I used this?

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        string connectionString;
        var host = ??????//Need to get the host name
        if ( host=="mydomain1.com")
        {
            connectionString = "\"Data Source=Data\\\\database1.db\";";
        }
        if (host == "mydomain2.com")
        {
            connectionString = "\"Data Source=Data\\\\database2.db\";";
        }
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connectionString);
    }
```

The current Project (Net Core) uses IHttpContextAccessor. In blazor IHttpContextAccessor is not supposed to be used.

Old Project
public partial class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext

```
   {
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
        : base(options)
    {
        _accessor = accessor;
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        string connectionString;
        var host = _accessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.Value;//Need to get the host name
        if ( host=="mydomain1.com")
        {
            connectionString = "\"Data Source=Data\\\\database1.db\";";
        }
        if (host == "mydomain2.com")
        {
            connectionString = "\"Data Source=Data\\\\database2.db\";";
        }
        var transactionApplicationTenant = TransactionApplicationTenantController.GetTransactionApplicationTenant(_accessor);
        optionsBuilder.UseSqLite(connectionString);
    }
```

As an example on a sample blazor page I can do the following within a component, but I need to do it within my OnConfiguring in ApplicationDbContext

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

@code {
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{

    var uri = new Uri(NavigationManager.Uri);
    string hostName = uri.Host;

}
```

}

Similar to this issue:

[Blazor server-side with multiple database based on hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66211375/blazor-server-side-with-multiple-database-based-on-hostname)

Answer (score 1):

When needing to choose a database connection string based on the hostname, I  recommend to configure your DbContext options at the application startup rather than within the DbContext itself. This approach allows you to inject necessary services to determine the connection string before your ApplicationDbContext is instantiated.

Blazor Server Solution
Enable IHttpContextAccessor in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    // Other service configurations...
}
```

Configure ApplicationDbContext with a Factory:

Inject the IHttpContextAccessor into a factory that creates your ApplicationDbContext, allowing you to select the connection string based on the request's hostname:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddScoped<ApplicationDbContext>(provider =>
    {
        var accessor = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        var host = accessor.HttpContext?.Request.Host.Host;
        string connectionString = DetermineConnectionString(host); // Implement this method based on your logic

        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connectionString);

        return new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    });
}
```

**Blazor WebAssembly Consideration**

For Blazor WebAssembly, directly accessing the hostname to configure the DbContext is not feasible due to its client-side nature. Typically, Blazor WebAssembly apps should interact with a server-side API for data operations, where database selection based on the hostname can be managed.